# What is Java Regex to check if a String is a chain of numbers delimited by "_" (java)?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a String  is a chain of numbers delimited by "_":

Examples:

```
200_121_545  : return true;
455          : return true;  // it doesn't need _ to be valid, a number is ok
ff_78        : return false;
2212 _55     : return false; // no space in the string
121212@44    : return false;
```

The number of numbers is unknown inadvanced. Ex: it could be 21212_545 or 45_545_78

Comment: You mean you cannot start with the number `0`?

Comment: 0323 is fine, but 00 is not ok, as logn as partInt(number) return 0 is not OK

Comment: @Tum Any chance you can handle the `00` problem somewhere else in your code? It will make the regex much more complicated to weed out those occurances. (Also, it seems very strange for `0123` to be ok, but `0012` not to be).

Comment: @Duncan - you could use a series of two regex matchings to cover the `00` constraint in a second step.

Comment: @Tum: 'logn as partInt(number) return 0 is not OK' - can you expand on that? Is the constraint that each number in the pattern must contain at least one non-zero digit?

Comment: Can you clarify the "no zeroes" requirement - are you saying that each section (beginning, end and between two `_` characters) must have at least one digit that isn't zero?  So `001_020_300` would be OK?  Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
s.matches("\\d*[1-9](_\\d+)*")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this match 000_123? even though it shouldn't

Comment: The pattern would be `_<number>`. The brackets ensure that there must be a `_` before the number.

Comment: @christopher: Looks good to me. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Awesome Evgeniy Dorofeev, thank you very much

Comment: This wouldn't catch 0123

Comment: -1 This is quite broken. It would allow arbitrary leading zeroes on any number after the first one. E.g. `123_000000` would match. At least, it seems broken compared to my understanding of the requirements...

Comment: The first test case is "200_121_545  : return true;" - this fails.

Comment: unfortunately you made your answer incorrect when you edited it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want each number to have at least one non-zero digit you may try something like this (updated with help of Tims comments):

```
^0*[1-9]\\d*(_0*[1-9]\\d*)*$
```

The `[1-9]` makes sure there is (at least) one non-zero digit in each group, where as the `0*` before allows any number of zeros. After that one non-zero digit, any digits including (but not only) zero can be allowed: `\\d*`.

Update 2: Added anchors as suggested by Daniël to make sure the whole string is matched.

Comment: Actually, you can drop the `+` - one digit in that range is enough, and you can reduce the number of permutations the regex engine has to check in the event of failure.

Comment: And to optimize the regex even further, use `0*` instead of the first `\\d*`: `0*[1-9]\\d*(_0*[1-9]\\d*)*`

Comment: I think you need to add anchors. As it stands it matches for example `0_1` which should not be allowed since the first of the 2 numbers is entirely zeros (i.e., `0`). It can match because there are no anchors, so the `0*[1-9]` does not have to apply at the start of the string now. The `0*` is just skipped, and `[1-9]` matches the `1` at the end of `0_1`. Since the rest is all zero-or-more, it just ignores it and matches. If you add `\A...\z` it will not match `0_1`, but I have not tested all other cases.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: Anchors are implicit when using Java's `.matches()` method. But it may be a good idea nonetheless, if only to make the intention clear.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh right, good point. I was actually testing the regex in another language (Ruby) and forgot this difference. Then I suppose it was correct to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands you will need to define your regexp of what you consider a number and repeat it. As far as I can tell you would like to have something like

```
s.matches("0[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*")
```

to match a single number string. As regexps cannot be factored you will need to repeat yourself for the `_`, as in

```
s.matches("0[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*(_(0[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*)*")
```

that should do the trick as long as you do not want `0` as an answer and you want to avoid double leading zeros. In all it is a horrible expression though.